# Curves with constant geodesic curvature in the hyperbolic plane

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Does anyone know which paper to cite or who to credit for the classification of curves of constant geodesic curvature in the hyperbolic plane?

Comment: I would guess Gauss...

Comment: Given your choice of language, perhaps the first paper by Beltrami on this. Stillwell would know.

Answer (score 3):

I would cite Coxeter, Non-euclidean geometry, Ch. XI, which is a secondary source.    Images of these curves are intersections of rectilinear planes with one sheet of a two-sheeted real hyperboloid.  Faithful images are intersections of rectilinear planes with one sheet of an imaginary sphere of radius 1, embedded in iR x iR x R.
If Gauss or Beltrami considered these curves, their treatments would have been less straightforward.  (Gauss did not publish his analyses of hyperbolic geometry.)